# How to make "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener" as a callback in background .js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have write a simple chrome extension needing a listener for updating tab in background.js. The extension has 3 steps below. Before that the content.js is triggered by browser action through background.js's message.

Step 1. I would like to send a url ("https://www.youtube.com/") from content.js to background.js.

Step 2. The background.js received the url and updated the tab.

Step 3. The background.js send back a message to content.js after the tab loaded.

The step 3 need a "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener". But as my script, this listener always triggered before the tab updated. I think the reason is the asynchronization of "chrome.tabs*" commands. So I need to nested these commands. How could I make "chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener" as a callback for "chrome.tabs.update"? or any other solution?

Thank you for any suggestion.

content.js

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "get the url"});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
                      port.postMessage({url: "https://www.youtube.com/"});
        }
        }
);
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.background == "step1"){
        console.log('back');
    }
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
  });
});
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.assert(port.name == "get the url");
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
// the problem is here
        chrome.tabs.update({url: msg.url});
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId , info) {
            if (info.status === 'complete') {
                alert('bbb');
                port.postMessage({background: "step1"});
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: 1) onUpdated sees all updates (including titles and favicons) in all tabs so you need to check if (tabId===port.sender.tab.id && info.url), 2) no need for chrome.tabs.query, simply use `tab` parameter of the onClicked listener.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you very much, especially for your first declaration.

Comment: @ As for your second point, please forgive my ignorance, "chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});
});" seems not OK. How to modify it?

Comment: Should use `tab.id` for sendMessage, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab) for the more details.